# error on line 1 at column 6: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document

Tags: php, xml

I was trying to build an XML file. But stuck with an error. I am including the code and error. Thanks in advance.

```
    <?php 
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()); 
    mysql_select_db("comrade") or die(mysql_error()); 
    $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM support WHERE DATE(`date`) = CURDATE()") 
    or die(mysql_error());
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<xml/>');
    while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
     { 
      $support = $xml->addChild('support');
      $support->addChild('cus_name',$info['com_name']);
      $support->addChild('ser_type',$info['ser_type']);
     } 

     Header('Content-type: text/xml');
     print($xml->asXML());
     ?>
```

It showing the following error

```
     Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

Comment: PHP starts with `<?php` and not just `?php`

Comment: Remove the spaces in the beginning of the file. `<?php` must start on the first position

Comment: @MonkeyZeus it happened when I pasted the code here. The syntax is correct in the php file. Still it remain unsolved. :(

Comment: Did you try @AleksG comment?

Comment: Yes, I do. There is no spaces in the beginning of the file

Comment: i tried your code, you have a space before <?php please remove that. oops am late, @AleksG is right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is the placement of `Header('Content-type: text/xml');`

Try this and make sure **NOTHING** comes before the `header()` call:

```
<?php 
header('Content-type: text/xml');

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("comrade") or die(mysql_error()); 
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM support WHERE DATE(`date`) = CURDATE()") 
or die(mysql_error());

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<xml/>');
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
{ 
    $support = $xml->addChild('support');
    $support->addChild('cus_name',$info['com_name']);
    $support->addChild('ser_type',$info['ser_type']);
} 

print($xml->asXML());
?>
```

Answer (score 12):

In short, you should do:

```
ob_clean(); //Clean (erase) the output buffer
print($xml->asXML());
```

explain: if any of the included files print a new line you will get

> error on line 2 at column 6: XML declaration allowed only at the start
>   of the document

it could be because in some file the `<?php` tag start after an empty line.

so instead of searching the file that cause the error, simply clean the output buffer.

Comment: After tens of hours looking for an empty line and not finding it, I have to say that this solution temporarily saves my life!

Comment: Basically, perform a ob_clean() before any output of any kind (json, xml, html ...) in order to prevent headers problems.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes saving UTF-8 with/without BOM could solve this (and similar) issues. Some special byte could exist in the very beginning of file in case of wrong saving method.